# Field() in MySQL any function in hive?

Tags: mysql, hive, field, hiveql

I am looking for a way in Hive which can do similar to Field() in MySQL

```
SELECT orderNumber,status FROM orders
ORDER BY 
    FIELD(status,
        'In Process',
        'On Hold',
        'Cancelled',
        'Resolved',
        'Disputed',
        'Shipped');
```

Which will return me orders as in specified order as below. Is any way I can achieve same in Apache Hive?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is the same [field function in Hive](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF#LanguageManualUDF-StringFunctions): `field(val T,val1 T,val2 T,val3 T,...)`

Returns the index of `val` in the `val1,val2,val3,...` list or `0` if not found. For example f`ield('world','say','hello','world')` returns `3`.
All primitive types are supported, arguments are compared using `str.equals(x)`. If val is NULL, the return value is 0.

Comment: I would like to order by records as per status. field in hive is more searching, Isn't it?

Comment: @subro It works the same as in MySQL. Use the same `ORDER BY 
    FIELD(status,
        'In Process',
        'On Hold',
        'Cancelled',
        'Resolved',
        'Disputed',
        'Shipped');`

Comment: So, it is getting order by 1,2,3,4..etc. Now I understand! thank you